# Unknown lifecycle phase "spring-boot"

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot Multi Module Project in which there is 3 libraries jar and a main application that uses these libraries.
This is the pom.xml of 1 of my modules

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.tdk-cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>tdk-cloud</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

  <groupId>com.tdk.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>tdk-web</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>



  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <!-- tdk-core dependencies -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tdk.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>tdk-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>           
        </dependency> 



        <!-- Webjars for JQuery and Bootstrap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7-1</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version> -->
        </dependency>


   </dependencies>




</project>
```

but when I  compile and run your application using `mvn spring-boot run`

I got this error:

```
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "spring-boot". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: you need maven spring boot plugin. add it to your pom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. **Add Spring Boot Maven Plugin** in your pom.xml

   ```
   <build>
           <plugins>
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                   <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
                   <executions>
                       <execution>
                           <goals>
                               <goal>repackage</goal>
                           </goals>
                       </execution>
                   </executions>
               </plugin>
           </plugins>
   ```
2. **To run your application**, Instead of

`mvn spring-boot run`

use

`mvn spring-boot:run`